# Trouble with WPA wifi connection - can connect to wireless networks

Tags: wireless, networking, broadcom, wpa2

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to set up wireless on a new install of Ubuntu Desktop 12.10.

I am able to connect to "open" wireless networks (I am connected to my house "guest" wifi network right now) - therefore the problem is not with the wireless card or firmware (I've done b43-fwcutter & firmware installs).

The issue is just when trying to connect to my WPA2 secure "normal" wifi network ("bkhouse").  It just won't seem to go...  It appears that I can connect to the SSID, but it won't complete the connection.

Help would be appreciated!!

```
brandon@linux-desktop:/etc/wpa_supplicant$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:64:db:89:16  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1517 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:944 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1802381 (1.8 MB)  TX bytes:95348 (95.3 KB)
          Interrupt:17 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:8926 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8926 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:737296 (737.2 KB)  TX bytes:737296 (737.2 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0f:66:6f:19:2c  
          inet6 addr: fd63:da35:957a:0:20f:66ff:fe6f:192c/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::20f:66ff:fe6f:192c/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: fd63:da35:957a:0:cc16:dc3c:c7f5:e400/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4397 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3964 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2716198 (2.7 MB)  TX bytes:827754 (827.7 KB)


brandon@linux-desktop:/etc/wpa_supplicant$ iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:"bkhouse"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 58:6D:8F:28:26:69   
          Bit Rate=48 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=63/70  Signal level=-47 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:40   Missed beacon:0
```

P.S. I've tried all kinds of different configurations with wpa_supplicant but haven't been able to sort anything out!

Answer (score 1):

You might need to edit /etc/network/interfaces to add the passkey, if you're not being given a chance to enter it manually when you connect.  See solution
here:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2059808

which references:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=202834

Or alternatively:
https://superuser.com/questions/42460/can-you-explain-how-to-understand-what-the-iwconfig-command-displays-in-ubuntu

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

I tried this, but I also realized I had previously reserved an IP for my desktop's MAC address on my router.... One of the two was probably the issue.